# Render and scroll through multiline paragraphs using pyglet and ScrollableTextLayout

Tags: python, scroll, multiline, pyglet

How can one display and scroll through a multi-line strings (contain "\n") via pyglet using the features of ScrollableTextLayout?

[STL crops what is display, and seems to be the most efficient way to implement scrolling.](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.text.layout-module.html)

However I have no idea as to how to use it. The docs do not elucidate much to me.

SomeText:

```
string = "Some multiline \n text is contained within this string \n which must be rendered \n such that it is able to be scrolled through."
```

Snippets/Links are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create one like this:

```
scroll_area = pyglet.text.layout.ScrollableTextLayout(my_text, width, height, multiline=True)
```

And you choose your scroll position with the view_x and view_y values.

```
scroll_area.view_y = 30 # start 30 pixels down
```

Set different values of view_y to scroll vertically.

Comment: How would one draw this to the screen?

Comment: Look at the docs for TextLayout, which ScrollableTextLayout derives from. There are only 8 methods so it shouldn't take you long.